# Reuse of AutoMapper configuration for nested child objects

Tags: c#, automapper

I am mapping between two complex objects and I have implemented an `ITypeConverter` which I use like...

```
 CreateMap<ChildDto, ChildViewModel>().ConvertUsing<ChildConverter>();
```

I also have a parent object...

```
 CreateMap<ParentDto, ParentViewModel>().ConvertUsing<ParentConverter>();
```

Now, `ParentDto` contains a number of instances of `ChildDto` and `ParentViewModel` contains a number of instances of `ChildViewModel`.

How do I configure AutoMapper to allow me to reuse the child mapping configuration at both levels?

For example, I can use...

```
 CreateMap<ChildDto, ChildViewModel>().ConvertUsing<ChildConverter>();
 CreateMap<ParentDto, ParentViewModel>()
     .ForMember(dest => dest.ChildA, opt => opt.MapFrom(src => src.ChildA)
     .ForMember(dest => dest.ChildB, opt => opt.MapFrom(src => src.ChildB)
```

...which maps the child properties correctly, but doesn't map the rest of the object. Or, I can use my existing...

```
  CreateMap<ParentDto, ParentViewModel>().ConvertUsing<ParentConverter>()
```

...which maps the rest of the object, but doesn't map the child properties. Within `ParentConverter` I can manually map the child properties, but it is possible to re-use the existing mapping logic rather than implement the same thing in two places?

Comment: I think you don't need the .ForMemeber calls on ParentDto. Automapper will see a property of type ChildDto and figure out that it needs to map it to a property with the same name of ChildViewModel type.

Comment: Ah, sorry, I oversimplified that example, the properties don't actually have the same name.  But anyway, because I have stuff to do in ParentConverter, AutoMapper doesn't act upon the children.  That seems to be my responsibility, whichs is fine, but I want to avoid implementing the same mapping in both places.